# Problem with Samsung Galaxy S2 Driver on Windows

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-kies, usb-drivers

I updated Kies today and my Samsung Galaxy S2 phone doesn't connect to my pc via Debug Mode any more.

Below is the screen shot

[image: Missing driver in Windows Device Manager]

When I uninstall that and try to reconnect I get an error saying driver install failed.

Comment: try uninstalling the drivers before reinstalling the new drivers.

Comment: That looks like Windows 7.  Are you running 32 bit or 64 bit edition?

Comment: 64 bit version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on that "SAMSUNG_Android" and select `Uninstall`.  Then make sure the `Delete the driver...` option is checked, and click the `OK` button.  This should clear out the old drivers from the system.  Now unplug the phone and try uninstalling and re-installing Kies.  Reboot the PC and try plugging the phone in again.

If you are on Windows 7 64-bit, you may be able to bypass Kies software by installing [this driver](http://www.mediafire.com/?mmzzyhkxq7n3bph) (remove the "SAMSUNG_Android" from Device Manager again before installing the driver.)

Comment: What do you do if there is no option to remove the files?