# Windows 8 driver error with SGS

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, windows, usb-drivers

Got a new computer with Windows 8 64 bit, In the last day, I tried to connect my Samsung Galaxy S (GT-I9000) but get a driver error when I plug it in. I tried looking in the Samsung's web site forums, for it but with no luck. I got no luck in any other forum site.

Any suggestions ? I tried this found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19770/samsung-galaxy-s2-driver-problem) also and it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing Kies?

Other Solution is,

Windows 8 will take some time to load and install drivers. Please keep you phone connected to Windows 8 in USB mode. It will install the driver.

Comment: I tried to follow your advise and install kies - no luck with that too...
I kept my phone connect and I got driver error message from windows so I don't think it is time related.

Answer (score 0):

1. First check if u have normal google adb drivers, if no then download them , put your device in usb debugging mode (this settings location depends upon your android OS version)
2. Go to Devices and printers in control panel -> go to properties of your device ( device should be connected) -> Change settings -> update driver -> Let me pick driver from my pc -> 
   adb interface -> (it will give u list of adb drivers on ur machice) if you find any Samsung driver there click on it and click next or finish. Else choose google adb interface driver and finish.
3. Your device should be working properly with proper drivers installed :)

Comment: how do I check if I have "normal adb drivers" ?

Comment: sry for late reply, u have this question means u dont have google normal adb drivers :P .. so search on google for google adb drivers and how to install them on windows..

Comment: on the android website it says to go to the manufacture site for the driver download. I couldn't find the GT-I9000 driver in the http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads (samsung site). In addition, I search the driver in other site that offer drivers but couldn't find the driver for win8 x64. Any suggestions ?

Comment: http://www.androidegis.com/how-to/install-adb-android-debug-bridge-and-device-drivers/

you can follow these steps.. its a hard way.. but can work :)